# How to get a div object to show if a text box is overflowing - Angular

Tags: angularjs, overflow, angular-ng-if

I have (what seems like) quite a simple problem, which I am struggling to solve as it seems to be a bit different to any other example I've found on the internet.

I have a text container, and if this overflows I want to show a new `<div>` containing some text ('more'). I also need the text to cut off short with an ellipsis. I suspect I need to manually create this behaviour rather than use CSS's `text-overflow: ellipsis` property, because I need the ellipsis to happen about 20px to the left of the end of the container.

To start with, I am just trying to get the 'more' `div` to show up if there is too much text. Here is my directive:

```
.directive('genericNotification', function($compile) {
  var openFuncNameErm = 'openErm';
  return {
    controller: 'ErmModalCtrl',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      title: '=',
      errorList: '=',
      errMsg: '=',
      error: '=',
      //.........
      showMore: '='
    },
    templateUrl: "src/alerts/templates/error-alert.html",
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var messageBox = element.find('.alert-text');
      if (messageBox.offsetHeight < messageBox.scrollHeight ||
          messageBox.offsetWidth < messageBox.scrollWidth) {
        scope.showMore=true;
      } else {
        scope.showMore=false;
      }

    }
  }
})
```

My templateURL file:

```
<div class='po-alert error' ng-show="error">
<div class="alert-icon">
    <img src="assets/error.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="alert-text">
    <p>{{error}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="showMore">
    more
</div>
```

and HTML:

```
<div generic-notification title='errorModal.title' error-list="errorModal.errorList" err-msg="mostRecentError" error="mostRecentError.message" info="mostRecentError.message"></div>
```

At this point, I have two main questions:

1) What is the best way (using Angular) to check whether the text is overflowing?

2) How do I get my 'more' `<div>` to show based on the result of the link function?